# Debug the Solr analyzer process

Tags: solr, lucene

I would like to see the result of the solr analyzers. Like this one:

```
 <fieldType name="text_stem" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-chars.txt" />
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Danish" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I search for tools that could read a lucene index and found Luke and another one with a front-end written in react. Both are not working with lucene >= 8.

What kind of workflow can I use to see if my analyzers are producing the expected result?

Comment: I would use the Analysis screen in the Solr Admin UI: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/analysis-screen.html

Comment: The analyzer screen is a good options. just wish there was a better tool.

Comment: @MartinAndersen what do you mean better? Could you define expected features which Admin UI lacking?

Comment: @MartinAndersen What information are you looking for that isn't available through the Analysis screen? It should tell you exactly what changes for each step in the analysis process for both your indexing and querying analyzer, as well as whether those changes results in a hit or not.

Comment: In Luke you can see all the fields at once, not just one filed at a time. I also find it annoying that the index selector is so narrow that you can not red the name.